# How to get the 'Want to see more from' - 'Like Page' button on playing a Flash based post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, shockwave, facebook-stream-story

When we click on a Sound Cloud shared URL, it will start the flash content. Along with that below the flash content we can see the following message as shown in the image, if we have not liked the Sound Cloud page yet.

```
[Want to see more from Sound Cloud? Like Page!][1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxsSV.png
```

So, my question is that how do I get the Like Page button on my Flash posts? They do not appear when I share my sample URL like http://www.pikspeak.com/show/64/peafowl even though I have set the `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="127871584024645" />`
 for that page.

Please, do tell if my question is not clear. I simply want what is shown in the image to come in my posts too. thanks in advance.

Comment: Also looking for how to do this...
Not a 'how to' - just some more info on it: [link](http://www.hasoffers.com/blog/facebooks-features-aim-brands-drive-conversions/)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a trial program they are testing. I don't think they have opened it up for everyone or if it even will be...

http://www.insidefacebook.com/2013/02/04/facebook-prompts-users-to-like-pages-associated-with-domains-their-friends-share/

http://www.hasoffers.com/blog/major-web-publishers-testing-facebook-campaign/