# Facebook page under links shared on timelines

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

if you try to share this link http://www.gamespot.com/articles/call-of-duty-strike-team-hits-android/1100-6415792/ on your timeline, you can see that on the bottom appear something like "do you want to see more posts by GameSpot?"

How is it possible this? Do I have to include something in the meta to link my facebook page to my website?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this "Like suggestion" feature is only available to specific companies right now. Some links about that topic:

- [How to get the 'Want to see more from' - 'Like Page' button on playing a Flash based post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511957/how-to-get-the-want-to-see-more-from-like-page-button-on-playing-a-flash-b)
- http://www.quora.com/Facebook-Sharing-and-Share-Button/How-do-publishers-get-their-links-to-include-a-want-to-see-more-from-with-a-Like-Page-button-when-shared-on-Facebook
- http://www.digitaltrends.com/social-media/facebook-is-frequently-testing-in-line-buttons-that-may-boost-engagement/